# How to use custom x axis label and y axis label in achartengine?

Tags: android, achartengine

I checked this [How to set value in x axis label in achartengine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904457/how-to-set-value-in-x-axis-label-in-achartengine?rq=1) whatever it gives null pointer exception. Can anyone guide how to set custom x axis label? I'm storing values in a String.

Answer (score 0):

To add a custom X axis text label:

```
renderer.addXTextLabel(x, "label");
```